# I'm having trouble with this function I am creating for reading lines from input

Tags: python, function, module

Can anyone help me with creating this module for coursework I'm having some trouble with it and would appreciate your help?[This is a picture of my code for the module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEZVW.png)

#!/usr/bin/env python

```
lines = []

def get():
    a = raw_input()
    while a != "end":
        lines.append(a)
        a = raw_input()
        return lines
```

Comment: you need to left indent you `return` statement to move it outside of `while` loop.

Comment: Yes that fixed that, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your code gets the input and append 'a' to lines if its not 'end' and then get another input. The last line `return lines` executes exactly **after** executing raw_input() which ends the loop and return from function.

As Krishna mentioned in the comments, the correct code for your use is:

```py
lines = []

def get():
    a = raw_input()
    while a != "end":
        lines.append(a)
        a = raw_input()
    return lines
```

This way, your `return lines` is **outside** of while loop, meaning that the while loop runs until it encounter 'end' and then executes `return lines`

Comment: @LeonardoShehu feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark beside the answer.